# Is there a more elegant way to input a map as a list of pairs from stdin in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Currently, as part of a coding practice exercise, I wrote the following code to read a set of space-separated pairs from stdin (as a trusted source) into a map, where `nbElevators` is previously defined:

`(let [elevators (into {} (doall (repeatedly nbElevators #(do [(read) (read)]))))]`

Is there a better way to do this?

- I don't like the `#(do`, but without this, Clojure constantly interpreted the `repeatedly` as an attempt to call the vector as a function, rather than treating the vector's appearence as representing a single form function which returns a vector. This seems odd because an expression is valid as a function body (eg, `(defn foo [] 2)` works), yet `(repeatedly 5 2)` doesn't, neither does `(repeatedly 5 #(2))` - even though `(repeatedly 5 (fn [] 2))` does, implying a hole in the reader macro. Am I missing something syntactic here?
- Can the `doall` be avoided? Is there some way to automatically cache or earmark the input so that the correct place in the file is read when sequence is evaluated lazily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point one, remember that in Clojure (and afaik, lisps in general), `()`s have a set, special meaning. Unless a macro rearranges things before evaluation, `(f a)` means that `f` will be called with `a` as an argument. This isn't a "hole" in the macro. I'd argue that it would be even more surprising if `#(2)` *didn't* attempt to call `2`. That would fly in the face of the otherwise consistent nature of how function calls work.

You can see what `#()` expands to using the special form [`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote):

```
(quote #(2))
=> (fn* [] (2))  ; fn* is the actual special form that fn delegates to

(quote #(vector %))
=> (fn* [p1__1632#] (vector p1__1632#))  ; % is translated to a generated symbol
```

Which shows what the problem is.

Personally, I'd use `(fn [] [(read) (read)])` there for clarity. That's more verbose, but as I'll mention at the end, the code in general can be cleaned up a bit so that that's not a problem.

Of course too, the whole anonymous function could be made into an actual standalone function if that helps clarity.

---

And if you want the `repeatedly` call to happen strictly, I'd use `vec` instead of `doall` and just force the lazy list into a vector. I honestly haven't found much use for `doall` that `vec` doesn't handle. There might be a small space-use difference, but I've never found it to be significant.

In this case though, neither is necessary. `into` will force the collection returned by `repeatedly` strictly. Maps aren't lazy, so it will need to be evaluated right away anyway.

---

---

And I'd just use a `->>` macro to split this so it isn't quite as long:

```
(let [elevators (->> (repeatedly nbElevators (fn [] [(read) (read)]))
                     (into {}))])
```

The `(fn [] . . .)` bit could even the argument being threaded, but I don't think that that would read as well, even if it would lead to shorter lines.

This could all also be re-written by making use of the [`hash-map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map) "constructor" as @amolloy mentions. It takes a var-arg list and treats them as pairs. This frees you up from needing to pair the key/values yourself:

```
(apply hash-map (repeatedly (* 2 nbElevators) read))
```

Comment: Thanks! I kind of misunderstood as I thought `#(x)` was equivalent to `(fn [] x)` not `(fn [] (x))`.

Comment: @MarkGreen Just for reference, try evaluating `(quote #(vector 1))`. You can see what `#()` expands to.